# Circuitikz Symbol: Circular sector

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to make a CircuiTikz Symbol as follows:

[image]

it is a monopole (the 'connection pin' is on the left). How can I do that?
I tried to reverse-engineer some of the existing symbols, but I was unable to find out how such a circular section could be made.

---

The monopole was a good idea. I have managed to write the code:

```
\pgfdeclareshape{radialstub}{\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin‌​} 
\behindforegroundpath{
  \pgfscope
    \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth 
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/th‌​ickness}
    \pgfstartlin‌​ewidth} 
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin} 
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{30}{6mm}} 
    \pgfpatharc{30}{150}{6mm} 
    \pgfpathclose 
    \pgfusepath{draw} 
  \endpgfscope } }
```

Comment: \pgfpatharc on page 988 of the tikz manual.

Comment: yes, but I need to include that in a CircuiTikz shape. I want something similar like a resistor.

Comment: You should use a monopole like ground as a template.  The connecting pin will be at the origin of the shape.

Comment: The monopole was a good idea. I have managed to write the code:

`
\pgfdeclareshape{radialstub}{\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
\behindforegroundpath{
    \pgfscope
        \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{30}{6mm}}
        \pgfpatharc{30}{150}{6mm}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    \endpgfscope
    }
}
`

Comment: BTW, you can answer your own question.  It might help to use a full MWE (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222424/circuitikz-dac-and-adc-shapes/223634?s=3|3.3235#223634 for example).  You can even accept your own answer (eventually).