# How to improve the creation of digital circuits in PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuits

I am currently designing a piece of hardware and wanted to document this in a Latex document. Luckily, there is `circuitikz` and `pgf` to work with. The building block I am interested in are not included in `circuitikz` so I decided to follow the guide for creating a multipole component [here](http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/multipole.pdf). Here are the blocks I have already drawn:[image]

As an example here is the code for the decoder:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.misc}

\tikzstyle{bus} = [near end, rotate=-110, strike out, draw, scale=0.6]
\def \busx {0.5pt}
\def \busy {2.5pt}

% ---------------
% Decoder
% ---------------
\pgfpoint{-1.8cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcsub}{\ydcsub}
\pgfpoint{-1.4cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcand}{\ydcand}
\pgfpoint{-1.0cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcor}{\ydcor}
\pgfpoint{-0.6cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcxor}{\ydcxor}
\pgfpoint{-0.2cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcnot}{\ydcnot}

\pgfpoint{0.2cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcdir}{\ydcdir}
\pgfpoint{0.6cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcrot}{\ydcrot}
\pgfpoint{1.0cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcar}{\ydcar}
\pgfpoint{1.4cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcmul}{\ydcmul}
\pgfpoint{1.8cm}{-1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xdcop}{\ydcop}

\pgfpoint{0cm}{1.0cm}
\pgfgetlastxy{\xinop}{\yinop}

\pgfdeclareshape{decoder}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
\inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
\anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}

\savedanchor\pindcsub{\pgfpoint{\xdcsub}{\ydcsub - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{sub}{\pindcsub}
\savedanchor\pindcand{\pgfpoint{\xdcand}{\ydcand - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{and}{\pindcand}
\savedanchor\pindcor{\pgfpoint{\xdcor}{\ydcor - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{or}{\pindcor}
\savedanchor\pindcxor{\pgfpoint{\xdcxor}{\ydcxor - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{xor}{\pindcxor}
\savedanchor\pindcnot{\pgfpoint{\xdcnot}{\ydcnot - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{not}{\pindcnot}
\savedanchor\pindcdir{\pgfpoint{\xdcdir}{\ydcdir - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{dir}{\pindcdir}
\savedanchor\pindcrot{\pgfpoint{\xdcrot}{\ydcrot - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{rot}{\pindcrot}
\savedanchor\pindcar{\pgfpoint{\xdcar}{\ydcar - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{ar}{\pindcar}
\savedanchor\pindcmul{\pgfpoint{\xdcmul}{\ydcmul - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{mul}{\pindcmul}
\savedanchor\pindcop{\pgfpoint{\xdcop}{\ydcop - 0.5cm}}
\anchor{s}{\pindcop}

\savedanchor\piniop{\pgfpoint{\xinop}{\yinop + 0.5cm}}
\anchor{iop}{\piniop}

\foregroundpath{
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.8pt}
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{2.2cm}{1.0cm}}{\pgfpoint{-2.2cm}{-1.0cm}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
    \pgftext[at={\pgfpointorigin}]{\large Decoder}

    \pgftext[top,at={\pgfpoint{\xinop - 0.1cm}{\yinop - 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize OP}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\xinop,\yinop) -- node[bus,rotate=90] (bus) {} ++(0,0.5cm);
    \node[circle] at ($(bus.west)+(\busx-2pt,\busy-8pt)$) {\tiny 5};

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcsub + 0.1cm}{\ydcsub + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize SUB}
    \draw (\xdcsub,\ydcsub) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcand + 0.1cm}{\ydcand + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize AND}
    \draw (\xdcand,\ydcand) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcor + 0.1cm}{\ydcor + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize OR}
    \draw (\xdcor,\ydcor) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcxor + 0.1cm}{\ydcxor + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize XOR}
    \draw (\xdcxor,\ydcxor) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcnot + 0.1cm}{\ydcnot + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize NOT}
    \draw (\xdcnot,\ydcnot) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcdir + 0.1cm}{\ydcdir + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize DIR}
    \draw (\xdcdir,\ydcdir) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcrot + 0.1cm}{\ydcrot + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize ROT}
    \draw (\xdcrot,\ydcrot) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcar + 0.1cm}{\ydcar + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize AR}
    \draw (\xdcar,\ydcar) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcmul + 0.1cm}{\ydcmul + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize MUL}
    \draw (\xdcmul,\ydcmul) -- ++(0,-0.5cm);

    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\xdcop + 0.1cm}{\ydcop + 0.3cm}},rotate=90]{\scriptsize RES}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\xdcop,\ydcop) -- node[bus,rotate=90] (bus) {} ++(0,-0.5cm);
    \node[circle] at ($(bus.west)+(-\busx-2pt,\busy)$) {\tiny 3};
    }
}
}
```

The other ones have a similar structure. I was now wondering if there is a less verbose / more automated way to create these blocks as they are extremely time consuming to make.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Anything repeated exactly, like the inherited anchors, could be put into a macro and reused (I created \compass for standard anchors).  Some things could be done using loops.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187068/pgfdeclareshape-how-to-define-anchors-in-a-loop?r=SearchResults&s=8|18.3721 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372993/is-it-possible-to-implement-multiple-input-logic-ports-with-circuitikz/372996?r=SearchResults&s=4|37.6021#372996

Comment: I might note that many of the recent changes in circuitikz consist of using macros to generate more than one component.  This simplifies the code, but makes modifications more difficult.  \drawfetcore is used for all FETs, for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the links. Where do I find \compass is it included in `circuitikz` or would I have to define it myself?

Comment: There is a copy in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222424/circuitikz-dac-and-adc-shapes/223634?r=SearchResults&s=4|9.7619#223634